# How can I read a integer data file into my following java code??? File name SortDatafile

Tags: java, computer-science

Think the problem is in my main class which i tried to add a scanner and a file reader. The code works using the set up number I have proved once you remove the scanner I tried to implement. I need it read different integer filled txt files.

```
public class SortAll
{
   private int[] sorArr;
private int[] MergArr;
private int length;

   public static int[] SelectionSort(int[] OrigArr)
   {
for (int i = 0; i < OrigArr.length - 1; i++)
{
int loc = i;
for (int j = i + 1; j < OrigArr.length; j++)
if (OrigArr[j] < OrigArr[loc])
loc = j;

int small = OrigArr[loc];
OrigArr[loc] = OrigArr[i];
OrigArr[i] = small;
}
return OrigArr;
}

   public static int[] InsertionSort(int[] OrigArr)
   {
       int temp;
       for (int i = 1; i < OrigArr.length; i++)
       {
           for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--)
           {
               if(OrigArr[j] < OrigArr[j-1])
               {
                   temp = OrigArr[j];
                   OrigArr[j] = OrigArr[j-1];
                   OrigArr[j-1] = temp;
               }
           }
       }
       return OrigArr;
   }

   public void sort(int originalArr[]) {
this.sorArr = originalArr;
this.length = originalArr.length;
this.MergArr = new int[length];
MergeSorting(0, length - 1);
}

private void MergeSorting(int low, int high) {

if (low < high) {
int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
// Sorting left side of sorArr in the below step
MergeSorting(low, mid);
// Sorting right side of sorArr in the below step
MergeSorting(mid + 1, high);
// Merging both parts
MergingParts(low, mid, high);
}
}

private void MergingParts(int low, int mid, int high) {

for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
MergArr[i] = sorArr[i];
}
int i = low;
int j = mid + 1;
int k = low;
while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
if (MergArr[i] <= MergArr[j]) {
sorArr[k] = MergArr[i];
i++;
} else {
sorArr[k] = MergArr[j];
j++;
}
k++;
}
while (i <= mid) {
sorArr[k] = MergArr[i];
k++;
i++;
}

}
public void quick(int[] inputArr) {

if (inputArr == null || inputArr.length == 0) {
return;
}
this.sorArr = inputArr;
length = inputArr.length;
quickSort(0, length - 1);
}

private void quickSort(int low, int high) {

int i = low;
int j = high;
//In the below step, we are calculating pivot number
int pivot = sorArr[low+(high-low)/2];
// Dividing the Array into two Arrays.
while (i <= j) {
while (sorArr[i] < pivot) {
i++;
}
while (sorArr[j] > pivot) {
j--;
}
if (i <= j) {
exchNum(i, j);
//Moving index to next position of the array
i++;
j--;
}
}
// calling quickSort() recursively
if (low < j)
quickSort(low, j);
if (i < high)
quickSort(i, high);
}

private void exchNum(int i, int j) {
int temp = sorArr[i];
sorArr[i] = sorArr[j];
sorArr[j] = temp;
}


   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       SortAll sortArr=new SortAll();
       long start;
       long end;
       long total;
       int[] outputArr;
       int[] randomNumArr={5,32,23,47,89,11,19,36,77,66};
       int[] equalNumArr={4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4};
       int[] sortedIncArr={11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111};
       int[] sortedDecArr={111,99,88,77,66,55,44,33,22,11};

       //Running Selection Sort on Random Array
       start=System.nanoTime();

       outputArr=SelectionSort(randomNumArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;
       System.out.println("Runtime For Selection Sort :\n");
       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Random Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Running Selection Sort on Equal Array      
       start=System.nanoTime();
       outputArr=SelectionSort(equalNumArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;      
       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Equal Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Running Selection Sort on Sorted Array Increasing order      
       start=System.nanoTime();
       outputArr=SelectionSort(sortedIncArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;      
       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Increasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Running Selection Sort on Sorted Array Decreasing order      
       start=System.nanoTime();
       outputArr=SelectionSort(sortedDecArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Decreasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Running Insertion Sort
       start=System.nanoTime();      
       outputArr=InsertionSort(randomNumArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;
       System.out.println("\nRuntime For Insertion Sort :\n");
       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Random Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Running Selection Sort on Equal Array      
       start=System.nanoTime();
       outputArr=InsertionSort(equalNumArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;      
       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Equal Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Running Selection Sort on Sorted Array Increasing order      
       start=System.nanoTime();
       outputArr=InsertionSort(sortedIncArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;      
       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Increasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Running Selection Sort on Sorted Array Decreasing order      
       start=System.nanoTime();
       outputArr=InsertionSort(sortedDecArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Decreasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Runtime for Merge Sort
       System.out.println("\nRuntime For Merge Sort :\n");
       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.sort(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Random Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.sort(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Equal Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.sort(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Increasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.sort(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Decreasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       //Runtime FOr QuickSort

       System.out.println("\nRuntime For Quick Sort :\n");
       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.quick(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Random Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.quick(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Equal Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.quick(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Increasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

       outputArr=randomNumArr;
       start=System.nanoTime();
       sortArr.quick(outputArr);
       end=System.nanoTime();
       total=end-start;

       for(int i:outputArr){
System.out.print(i);
System.out.print(" ");
}
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("--Sorted in Decreasing Order Array : "+total+" nanoseconds.\n");

   }

}
```

Comment: Only post the relevant stuff and what is the exact issue you are having?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have a SortDatafile.txt.  How to read integer values from text file in my java code above

Comment: So what went wrong when you tried creating a `Scanner` and using its `nextInt` method?

Comment: Should i remove these lines of code::::::int[] outputArr;
       int[] randomNumArr={5,32,23,47,89,11,19,36,77,66};
       int[] equalNumArr={4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4};
       int[] sortedIncArr={11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111};
       int[] sortedDecArr={111,99,88,77,66,55,44,33,22,11};

Comment: them insert a scanner and a nextInt ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// provide file object to Scanner
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\dsingh70\\Desktop\\temp\\SortDatafile.txt"));
    // if you have inputs (like 5,32,23,47,89,11,19,36,77,66) in file(comma
    // separated)
    // you need to reset the delimiter using below method;

    // s.useDelimiter(",");

    // if you have a numbers file with space separated (like 5 32 23 47 89
    // 11 19 36 77 66) you don't need above s.useDelimiter(",") method,
    // because space is default Delimiter in Scanner

    // iterate while file have integers
    int num;
    while (s.hasNextInt()) {

        num = s.nextInt();
        // provide your business logic
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```